# How to start Emacs from the Terminal window as a GUI application (macOS)

Tags: osx, gui

I've installed Emacs via Homebrew. The version that got installed is 25.3.1. It was installed as the file whose full path is `/usr/local/bin/emacs`. When I execute

```
emacs
```

at a Terminal window, Emacs starts inside the self-same window as a console application. How can I cause it to start as a GUI application?

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16810036) won't work, because the version of Emacs installed as `/Applications/Emacs` is 25.1.1 .

---

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

Comment: If you don't like the end result of what other answers posted, you can just try `xemacs` instead :)

Comment: `brew install --cask emacs` installs [Emacs.app](https://emacsformacosx.com/), and  `brew install emacs` installs [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) without GUI into `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you follow the install instructions in the wiki?

http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Installing_Emacs_on_OS_X

Basically, you need to install it with cocoa, it adds the GUI support.

```
$ brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

If you are willing to use spacemacs, then they recommend installing emacs-plus.
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs

```
$ brew tap d12frosted/emacs-plus
$ brew install emacs-plus
$ brew linkapps emacs-plus
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Where is it recommended to install emacs-plus?

Comment: If you use Spacemacs on OSX, the documentation suggest you install emacs-plus.

Comment: The required command is now `brew install --cask emacs` (as noted in a comment above that I missed on first glance)

Answer (score 34):

According to [Emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS) "Homebrew has Emacs 26.1 as of January 2019" and "Homebrew now recommends to use the cask version".

The message that Homebrew gives is "Please try the Cask for a better-supported Cocoa version".

I tried `--with-cocoa` myself in February 2019 and is not supported any more.

`linkapps` also doesn't work any more.

Use this command to install Emacs with Cocoa.

```
brew cask install emacs
```

This works for Emacs 26.1 upwards.

The command `brew cask install` was changed to `brew install --cask` instead. You will get a warning for now, but it might lead to errors in the future. Use the following command instead.

```
brew install --cask emacs
```

Comment: Thanks. What is your answer based on? Could you link to a source, please?

Comment: Added some sources :)

Comment: Great. Thanks. +1

Comment: Same experience as ayckoster. Confirming that it worked for me a/o Apr 30. 2019.

Comment: Doesn't work now.

Comment: `brew install --cask emacs` worked for me. Thanks

Comment: It's better to put the latest method first.

Comment: I'm curious how this works with the `brew upgrade` command - would you still need `--cask`? What if you didn't use it initially?

Answer (score 0):

Even though I use brew, I find it easier to directly download and install emacs [from the official website](https://emacsformacosx.com/) due to these GUI issues.