# I need help for the Emacs in GUI in Macos catalina since it is opening only in terminal

Tags: osx, gui-emacs, emacs27

I have macOS Catalina. I just installed emacs 27. version but it's only in the terminal not in a different display of its own (i think that is called GUI). Please suggest for GUI.

Comment: My I asked how did you install it?

Comment: I installed it using dmg file later linked it from brew command.

Comment: Then [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47774/19426) might help.